# Error while passing value in a r function during tree creation

Tags: r

I'm attempting to use this code for tree creation starting from a data.frame.

```
library(data.tree)

# Creates table "mbom"
mbom <- data.frame(
  Lev. = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4),
  item = c("A", "B", "D", "E", "C", "F", "D", "E"),
  father = c(NA, "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "F", "F")
)

# Function for tree creation
create_tree <- function(dataframe1, node_name = "A") {
  node <- Node$new(node_name)

  subset_dataframe1 <- subset(dataframe1, father == node_name)
  if (nrow(subset_dataframe1) > 0) {
    for (i in 1:nrow(subset_dataframe1)) {
      children <- subset_dataframe1$item[i]
      node_children <- create_tree(dataframe1, children)
      node$AddChild(node_children)
    }
  }
  
  return(node)
}

# Tree creation
mbom_tree <- create_tree(mbom)
```

The output expected is:

```
  levelName
1  A
2  ¦--B
3  ¦   ¦--D
4  ¦   °--E
5  °--C
6      °--F
7          ¦--D
8          °--E
```

But at the line

```
mbom_tree <- create_tree(mbom)
```

the code  generates the error:

```
Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'
Called from: as.character.default(name)
```

I've tried to reinstall data.frame package but the error remains.
As soon as I resolve this small  example, I'll extend to a  hierarchical structure made of thousands of rows and many levels of structure.

Comment: Do you really need a custom function here? Why don't you rearrange your data and use `as.Node()`?

Comment: Because as.Node works with a tree having leaves all at the same level. My tree has leaves sometimes at level 3, sometimes at 4 as the tree posted before. I've tried as.Node before the tentative of code posted here but the result is a tree with a non-expected structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, there is no need for writing a custom function here. Rearrange your data and create a helper string which defines the path. Then you can use `as.Node()`. Here is one example (which can be even more simplified, I guess):

```
library(data.tree)

mbom <- data.frame(
    father = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
    item = c("B", "B", "C", "C"),
    item2 = c("D", "E", "F", "F"),
    item3 = c(NA, NA, "D", "E")
)

mbom$pathString <- do.call(paste, c(mbom,
                                    sep = "/")) |>
    stringr::str_replace_all("/NA", "")

as.Node(mbom)

      levelName
1 A            
2  ¦--B        
3  ¦   ¦--D    
4  ¦   °--E    
5  °--C        
6      °--F    
7          ¦--D
8          °--E
```

Comment: Ok, it's clear. But my input is a 3 column table with level, father and children (or children and father doesn't matter) in xlsx format normally (sorry I omitted this passage in the original question with the intent to semplify my issue).

Comment: Then you will bring the `.xlsx` into R, and rearrange the data into the needed format, is there a problem?

Comment: Yes, but I have to post a new question for it.  Many thanks Jan!